# Why can't I log in after unistalling Python 2.7 and installing Python 3?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, login, python, uninstall

I uninstalled the Python 2.7 package to try and upgrade to Python 3. I uninstalled Python 2.7, and noticed some of my launcher items were completely gone. At this point I had installed Python 3. Now on reboot, I can't log in and the background for the log-in screen is black with white dots. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. - This is running 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. I still have the same version Live CD.

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback! But I can't boot into text mode, only boot from the Live CD, and I can't connect to the internet because I installed the Debian .tar.gz package usb_modeswitch for Mobile Broadband. Is there a way to copy the Python 2.7 parts of the OS from the Live CD and inject them into my system? The only thing I can think of is get a 12.04 Live CD and click 'Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04' option, but for reasons I won't go into this is impractical for me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to, and you shouldn't, uninstall python2.7 to install python3. You can have both packages installed at the same time. Many parts of Ubuntu require python2.7. Reinstall the packages you've uninstalled, and that should fix the problem. If you're having a problem installing python3 while python2.7 is installed, or you are having trouble getting python code to run in python3 instead of python2.7, please edit your question to include the relevant details.

If you're not sure which `python2.7` related packages you removed, you can look in the log files that start with `dpkg` and are located in `/var/log`. If the removal operations were pretty recent, you can just look in `/var/log/dpkg` itself (i.e., the file called just `dpkg` and located in the `/var/log` folder).

Answer (score 1):

I think many applications have strong dependencies with Python 2.7. But you can install Python 3 without uninstalling Python 2.7.
So, if you can login in text mode, just type this in order to install Python 2.7:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

Then you can reboot your computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

If I understand you, you have Python 3 installed. But if not, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

This last line does not uninstall Python 2.7.

Ariel.